# Searching for a string in a file (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I have been using:

```
open("some.txt") { |f| f.each_line.detect { |line| /re/.match(line) } }
```

This only shows me the first time that string appears in that file. How do I print out ALL of the lines that contain that string.

Comment: `File.readlines("some.txt").select { |line| /re/.match(line) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the behavior you are looking for with something like this:

```
File.open("some.txt") do |f|
  f.each do |line|
    puts line if line =~ /re/
  end
end
```

If you actually want an array with each line matching a regex, `#find_all` is the way to go:

```
File.open("some.txt") do |f|
  lines = f.find_all {|line| line =~ /re/ }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

[`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) only returns the first one.  [`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) will give you an array of all lines that match.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Some Guy answer.

You also have [#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) which I think is more commonly used.

Bonus: You can use the method [#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead of a `regex#match`. It should be a little faster, and in your case works perfectly.

```
open("some.txt") { |f| f.each_line.select { |line| line['re'] } }
```

Comment: select is an alias for find_all

Comment: @SomeGuy I see it more often. Anyway, it's just my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough.  I find it interesting that detect and find_all are the originals, and find and select alias to them.  IMHO it would make more sense for detect/select or find/find_all to be paired.  Random thought.

Comment: In `Eunumerable` `select` and `find_all` are the same: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L3240-L3241, but `Array#select` is different: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/array.c#L5658. `Array#find_all` falls back to the `Enumerable` version. So it may be that `select` is faster when dealing with arrays. In this case it looks like they are the same though.